# How to place views inside of CoordintaeLayout

Tags: android

I cant choose the location for my Views when I use Coordinate layout , when I put views inside of it , like (TextView & ImageView )  all the views are located in the same location .
My coordinate Layout contain ImageView and FloatingActionButton . 
for example , when I try to put TextView , it located on ( left , top ) side of the screen

this is pic for my layout 
[image]

everything I put  ,, it located to the top left of the screen 
over the ImageView

this my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="160dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/imageView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        />
```

My question ,,, how can I locate my Views inside of coordinateLayout

Answer (score 1):

> when I put views inside of it , like (TextView & ImageView ) all the
>   views are located in the same location

`CoordinatorLayout` extends from `FrameLayout` and just like `FrameLayout` views are stacked one on top of the other.

`CoordinatorLayout` does include some options to help you put views in specific positions.

You can use:

```
app:layout_anchor="@id/imageView"
app:layout_anchorGravity="top|left|start"
```

for the FAB to make it appear on top of the `ImageView`.

Check out [cheesequare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) by Chris Banes for more.

Comment: my problem is when I tried to put TextView below the floating action Button

Comment: maybe wrap the `TextView` + FAB in a `LinearLayout`?